# weird behivior undefined with PreTrainedTokenizer __init__

Tags: python, huggingface

so this took me a while to catch and I am still not 100% sure whats going on seems like the type of things r switching for no reason as if by magic. the behvior goes away as soon as I remove the inhertance but here is the code

```
class TokompilerHF(PreTrainedTokenizer):
    '''
        Hugging Face compatible version of Tokompiler
    '''
    def __init__(self, vocab_file, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tokompiler = Tokompiler(vocab_file)
        pad_token_id=self.tokompiler.encoder['[UNK]']
        #black magic for some reason removing the print changes
        print(type(pad_token_id))
        print(pad_token_id)
        self.pad_token_id=None
        self.pad_token_id=pad_token_id 
        print(type(self.pad_token_id))
        print(self.pad_token_id) 

class TokompilerHF(PreTrainedTokenizer):
    '''
        Hugging Face compatible version of Tokompiler
    '''
    def __init__(self, vocab_file, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tokompiler = Tokompiler(vocab_file)
        pad_token_id=self.tokompiler.encoder['[UNK]']
        #black magic for some reason removing the print changes
        print(type(pad_token_id))
        print(pad_token_id)
        self.pad_token_id=None
        self.pad_token_id=pad_token_id 
        print(type(self.pad_token_id))
        print(self.pad_token_id)

    def _tokenize(self, text, **kwargs):
        return self.tokompiler.tokenize(text)

    def _convert_token_to_id(self, token):
        return self.tokompiler.encode(token)

    def _convert_id_to_token(self, index):
        return self.tokompiler.decode([index])

    def convert_tokens_to_string(self, tokens):
        return ' '.join(tokens)

    def _convert_tokens_to_ids(self, tokens):
        return [self._convert_token_to_id(token) for token in tokens]

    def _convert_ids_to_tokens(self, ids):
        return [self._convert_id_to_token(id) for id in ids]

    def get_vocab(self):
        return self.tokompiler.encoder.copy()

    @property
    def vocab_size(self):
        return len(self.tokompiler.encoder)
tokenizer=TokompilerHF('tokenizer_vocab/vocab.txt')
```

now this prints

<class 'int'>
4
<class 'list'>
[4]

expected that if I assin a value that value dosent change 1 line of code after